# Locking Sliding Closet Doors

Tags: doors, lock, closet

I need to lock my bedroom closet doors.  There are two doors that can slide - one door in front, and one door behind. (*Bypass doors*)

There is an overlap in the center of the two of about 2.5 inches  when the doors are closed.  The track is on the top and they are hollow core.

I need to have the hardware for the locks screwed on the inside or back of the doors so that someone can't just take a screwdriver and unscrew the hardware and get into my closet.

I have researched and searched the market several times and haven't found anything to accomplish this. Can this be a project that has to be made at home rather than purchased?  HELP!!

Comment: Why do you need to lock your closet doors, especially given that they are hollowcore doors that won't withstand any sort of serious physical attack to begin with?

Comment: Sliding doors can be easily lifted off the tracks.

Comment: They make locks for the doors on the back of jewelry cases. You'll need something like that that will work with a thicker door.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option i found.
[image]

[This lock](https://www.thehardwarehut.com/search-product-result.php?search_prod_no=pb1068&searchb=Search) will work, it comes in brass or silver color. [Here is a YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRAm7mB8W5g) showing it in action.

It only requires a drill, the proper size drill bit or hole saw (*1 inch*) and a Philips screwdriver.

Comment: Thank you - yes I think it will work.  I also like the video right after it that shows the same lock being used in a regular door.  You couldn't slide anything between the lock and the frame to spring it open.